# Promise.all and wait all whatever it error

Tags: javascript, promise

I know Promise.all will wait all Promise resolved or one Promise rejected.
how can I make it wait all Promise resolved or rejected?

Comment: [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) _returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise._

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `Promise.allSettled()`.

> The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.
>
> Source: [Promise.allSettled() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function in this way. This function will always succeed without rejection.

```
const reflect = p => p.then(v => ({v, status: "fulfilled" }),
                            e => ({e, status: "rejected" }));

reflect(promise).then((v => {
    console.log(v.status);
});
```

And then you can apply `Promise.all` in this way, and can filter result depending on results of individual Promise.

```
Promise.all(arr.map(reflect)).then(function(results){
    var success = results.filter(x => x.status === "fulfilled");
});
```